# Which permissions/policies for IAM role to be used with CloudWatch monitoring script

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-iam

With CloudWatch monitoring script (mon-put-instance-data.pl) it's possible to specify a IAM role name to provide AWS credentials (--aws-iam-role=VALUE).

I'm creating a IAM role for this purpose (to run mon-put-instance-data.pl on an AWS instance), but which permissions / policies should I give to this role??

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Amazon CloudWatch Monitoring Scripts for Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-perl.html) are comprised of two Perl scripts, both using one Perl module - a short peek into the source reveals the following AWS API actions being used:

- `CloudWatchClient.pm` - [DescribeTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeTags.html)
- `mon-get-instance-stats.pl` - [GetMetricStatistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html), [ListMetrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_ListMetrics.html)
- `mon-put-instance-data.pl` - [PutMetricData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html)

With this information you can assemble your [IAM policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html), e.g. via the [AWS policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) - an all encompassing policy would be:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
        "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
        "ec2:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course you can drop `cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics` `cloudwatch:ListMetrics`when just using `mon-put-instance-data.pl` - please note that I haven't actually tested the code though.

Comment: These actions match the actions listed in the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-getstarted

Answer (score 2):

The above policy gives error asking for version.

The following should work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1426849513000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:SetAlarmState"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an Amazon provided IAM policy for CloudWatch. No need to build your own.
CloudWatchFullAccess

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't want to give full access to CloudWatch though... I don't want to give DeleteAlarms permission for example.

Comment: For dynatrace service this is perfect!

Comment: IMHO, for almost any 'monitoring' use-case, this is too much access. Your monitoring script doesn't need to (say) create or delete metrics or dashboards. The policy adds some fairly safe looking non-cloudwatch permissions, but then adds all of these too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/permissions-reference-cw.html. At a rough guess, `CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess` would be a safe 'first try', but even that may be overly generous.